# break word inside a table-cell div

Tags: html, css

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nVWt5/ with a structure like:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
<tr>
<td>
<span style="display:table-cell">
 <div style="word-wrap:break-word;">really_long_text_here_no_spaces</div>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I make the text wrap without modifying the span's display style? The span cannot be currently changed as it is autogenerated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `display:table-cell`, as it serves no useful purpose here and appears to prevent the wrapping.

A `span` element cannot contain a `div` element by HTML rules, so you should really do something to the markup.

Note that contrary to what the names suggest, `word-wrap:break-word` does not deal with words; instead, it mechanically breaks strings with no regard to rules of human languages.

Comment: Thanks, I can change the span into a div. However, I cannot remove the display:table-cell as it has purpose for another functionality and I don't want to have regressions. So the issue is how to have text breaking while preserving the table-cell display.

Comment: Then you need to describe the problem in a form that covers this other functionality. (Any functionality that relies on `display: table-cell` won’t work on some old browsers still in use, so it would be better to find a different approach, if possible.)

Comment: I only need to support IE8 and FF3.5 or later. These support the table-cell display. The other functionality is about aligning the texts in a certain way and I'd prefer not to change it to something else as it would require major refactorings

Comment: is there any reason for why display:table-cell prevents the wrapping?